# get subset of table based on unique column values

Tags: bash, awk, sed

H- I am looking for a bash/awk/sed solution to get subsets of a table based on unique column values. For example if I have:

```
chrom1 333
chrom1 343
chrom2 380
chrom2 501
chrom1 342
chrom3 102
```

I want to be able to split this table into 3:

```
chrom1 333
chrom1 343
chrom1 342


chrom2 380
chrom2 501


chrom3 102
```

I know how to do this in R using the split command, but I am specifically looking for a bash/awk/sed solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative `awk` which keeps the original order of records within each block

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] ORS $0:$0}
    END{for(k in a) print a[k] ORS ORS}' file
```

generates

```
chrom1 333
chrom1 343
chrom1 342


chrom2 380
chrom2 501


chrom3 102
```

there are 2 trailing empty lines at the end but not displayed in the formatted output.

Comment: No this won't maintain the original order due to use of associative array

Comment: I meant the order of records within each block, not the blocks themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know if this `awk` is of any use but it will create 3 separate file based on the unique column values:

```
awk '{print >> $1; close($1)}' file
```

Comment: by the way - do you get any additional control over the resulting file names?  i.e. add a trailing `.out` to each file name?

Comment: Sorry for the delay if you make the `awk` like this: `awk '{print >> "out_"$1; close($1)}'` file.... it will print `out_` before each new file

Answer (score 1):

Using `sort` and `awk`:

```
sort -k1,1 file | awk 'NR>1 && p != $1{print ORS} {p=$1} 1'
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want to keep **original order of records** from input file then use:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' '!($1 in a){a[$1]=$0; ind[++i]=$1; next}
   {a[$1]=a[$1] RS $0}
   END{for(k=1; k<=i; k++) print a[ind[k]]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

## create input list file.txt

```
(
cat << EOF
chrom1 333
chrom1 343
chrom2 380
chrom2 501
chrom1 342
chrom3 102
EOF
) > file.txt
```

## transfomation

```
cat file.txt  | cut -d" " -f1 | sort -u | while read c
do 
cat file.txt | grep "^$c" | sort
echo
done
```